# Oscilloscope input impedance when using a preamplifier

Tags: oscilloscope, input, coupling

I am currently measuring the power consumption from a SoC. With the aim of reducing quantization noise due to the small amplitude of the signal (less than mV), I am connecting a R&S HZ-16 preamplifier in the input channel of the oscilloscope. Now I was wondering which input coupling I should use, i.e., DC50 \$\Omega\$ or DC1M \$\Omega\$. At the moment I am using DC50 Ohm but since I am quite new into this field I would like to know whether this is correct or not and your opinions/suggestions (indeed any reference for further understanding this question would be very useful as well).

Regards ;-)

Edit 1:
In some manuals it is said that the input and output are provided as 50 \$\Omega\$ BNC connectors so, am I using the correct coupling?

Comment: What does the manual of your amp say?

Comment: That is one of the problems, there is no manual. Even taking a look into the website of the vendor does not provide any additional documentation.

Comment: Ok, I have found some info by reading the manual of a related product. It says "The input and output are provided as 50 Ohm BNC connectors to allow you to use any spectrum analyzer"

Comment: DC50 or DC1M - what is that the input of; the o-scope or the preamp. Also, what is the impedance of the circuit you're measuring?

Comment: DC50 or DC1M is the input of the oscilloscope.

Comment: About the impedance of the circuit I am not very sure (as I said I am quite new in this field) but I can let you know that I am measuring the voltage drop over a 1\$\Omega\$ resistor inserted into the Vdd path of the target chip (an FPGA in this case).

Comment: How are you coupling the voltage from your 1ohm resistor into the preamp? In general, you should connect the preamp to the scope with 50-ohm coax, and set the scope impedance to 50 ohms. Note that not all coax is 50 ohms, so check to make sure. Video coax, for instance, is normally 75 ohms.

Comment: This whole train of thought (that I was just put on by the other question) is an exercise in X-Y problem solving. First of all is your amp made to start at 100kHz, at which point you measure switching noise at best. Second of all, if your DC current causes less than a mV, you just need a bigger resistor, possibly followed by a bigger capacitor to take the peaks out. Total cost less than a dollar, savings 98%. Unless of course you have one of those fabled FPGAs that runs on 0.1V

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a high frequency pre-amp it will be designed with 50 ohm input impedance and the 20dB gain assumes that it is feeding a 50 ohm load.  Set the scope to 50 ohm input.  If it had been a low frequency amplifier then it could have expected to feed a high-impedance load.  The gain will be 6db higher with high a high-impedance load.

It will have 50ohm input impedance as well that may not be suitable for your use.
There is no mention of the low frequency response.

Answer (score 0):

The R&S HZ-16 has a specified bandwidth of 100 kHz to 3 GHz. Therefore, it is a reasonable assumption that its input and output impedance are both 50 ohms since that is the standard impedance at GHz frequencies.  Furthermore, since it is not DC coupled, it is probably not suitable for your measurement. However, if you want to use it, I would recommend setting your scope to 50 ohms input.